# How can I align a certain digit in a list with printf?

Tags: java, printing, printf

I'm trying to format my printf statement(s) so that the ones digits of all the outputs are aligned, for example

```
Sum:                        45
Average:                    22.50
Difference:                  5
Product:                   500
Distance:                    5
Maximum:                    25
Minimum:                    20
```

I am using

```
System.out.printf("%.30s%30d%n", "Sum:", getSum());
System.out.printf("%.30s%30f%n", "Average:", getAverage());
```

but that yields the result in a weird way:

```
Sum:                           233
Average:                      0.002155
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `System.out.printf("%-15s%10.2f%n", "Sum:",  getSum()); System.out.printf("%-15s%10.2f%n", "Average:", getAverage());`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
System.out.printf("%.30s%30f%n", "Sum:", (double)getSum());
System.out.printf("%.30s%30f%n", "Average:", getAverage());
```

**Output**

```
Sum:                    233.000000
Average:                  0.002155
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't solve the problem, just moves the decimal point over in the second print statement. I'm looking to align the ones place in all of the print statements. Thank you though.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It should work now as long as you don't mind trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities.  Pick the one that you like.

```
System.out.printf("%-10s%10d%n", "Sum:", 100);
System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f%n", "Average:", 3.5);

System.out.printf("%10s:%10d%n", "Sum", 100);
System.out.printf("%10s:%10.2f%n", "Average", 3.5);
```